# Run spring-boot sample application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run spring-boot application, but got an error

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forInstance(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.resolveDefaultEventType(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:278)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at io.fourfinanceit.homework.Application.main(Application.java:10)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I googled this error but did not find any solution to run the application.
My system settings

```
bosone@bosone:~/NetBeansProjects/test$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-78-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ofg.loans</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot-homework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: What is your spring Version?

Comment: @yugo spring-boot version is 1.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: I mean spring framework version.. is that 4.2 or something else? What is the exact version?

Comment: Added my pom.xml. I think Spring framework version is 4.0.0 or last RELEASE version

Comment: Replace the spring security dependency with the `spring-boot-starter-security dependency. Remove JUnit and mockito as those are already including in the `spring-boo-starter-test` dependency. Remove the version tags for guava, jackson and h2. All those are already managed by Spring Boot. You might want to include the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a `dependencyManagement` part (see the boot reference guide). The issue is you are messing around with the certified versions that work with boot and updating them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just fixed it. The app was not able to resolve the spring boot, because of the version - so just try playing with these lines and versions and scopes. Are you sure for the "test" :)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This resolves the issue temporarily but gives rise to another resolvable issue. Apart why should i add this dependency if my project dosent require. If my project requires this, it would give me compile time error than runtime error.

Comment: no idea we may have been on some tutorial or something long ago :D does not look relevant any more... and this ${spring.boot.version}, you can just hardcode, not use that variable here

Answer (score -3):

The method ResolvableType.forInstance(Object) came in 4.2, so I suggest you to update your Spring core version to 4.2.4

Comment: As I understood I must change <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> ?

Comment: Spring Boot imports a compatible version of Spring Framework and OP clearly doesn't override if. Better advice would be to suggest upgrading Spring Boot go 1.2.8 or 1.3.2.

Comment: @kryger updated my Spring Biit to 1.3.2 and got another error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService

Comment: A new problem = a new question (with all details included directly in its body)